# How to bind to a specific IQueryable during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011

**How can I avoid repeated code?**

I've got a controller --> service architecture where the controller will call a method in the service. For example below we have an `AccountController` that will call `GetCrmAccount` on the `AccountService`:

```
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IAccountService _AccountService;

        [Route("Account({AccountGuid:guid})", Name = "GetAccountByGuid")]
        [HttpGet]
        [CacheOutput(ServerTimeSpan = 300)]
        public Account GetAccountByGuid(Guid AccountGuid)
        {
            var Account = _AccountService.GetCrmAccount(AccountGuid);
            return Account;
        }
}
```

And my service:

```
    public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    private readonly XrmServiceContext _xrmServiceContext;

    public AccountService(XrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext)
    {
        _xrmServiceContext = xrmServiceContext;
    }
    public chr_servicelocation GetCrmLocation(Guid locationGuid)
    {
        return _xrmServiceContext.chr_servicelocationSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == locationGuid);
    }
```

My issue is that I have very similar requirements for other controllers. For example, I can have a controller called `AccountLeadsController` which will have its own service `AccountLeadsService`, that will have that same method `GetCrmAccountLead`, that will also be returning:

```
_xrmServiceContext.AccountLeadSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == accountLeadGuid);
```

**Rather than having to create this method for every service in my solution, is there a way that I could abstract this behavior?**

Here's the definition of the class that has the IQueryables:

```
    /// <summary>   Gets CRM Account by Guid. </summary>
    /// <param name="AccountGuid">  Guid of the Account to fetch. </param>
    /// <returns>   The CRM Account. </returns>
    public chr_serviceAccount GetCrmAccount(Guid AccountGuid)
    {
        return _xrmServiceContext.AccountSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == AccountGuid);
    }

/// <summary>
    /// Represents a source of entities bound to a CRM service. It tracks and manages changes made to the retrieved entities.
    /// </summary>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("CrmSvcUtil", "5.0.9690.3339")]
    public partial class XrmServiceContext : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public XrmServiceContext(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService service) : 
                base(service)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a binding to the set of all <see cref="Xrm.Account"/> entities.
        /// </summary>
        public System.Linq.IQueryable<Xrm.Account> AccountSet
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CreateQuery<Xrm.Account>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a binding to the set of all <see cref="Xrm.AccountLeads"/> entities.
        /// </summary>
        public System.Linq.IQueryable<Xrm.AccountLeads> AccountLeadsSet
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CreateQuery<Xrm.AccountLeads>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a binding to the set of all <see cref="Xrm.ActivityMimeAttachment"/> entities.
        /// </summary>
        public System.Linq.IQueryable<Xrm.ActivityMimeAttachment> ActivityMimeAttachmentSet
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CreateQuery<Xrm.ActivityMimeAttachment>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a binding to the set of all <see cref="Xrm.ActivityParty"/> entities.
        /// </summary>
        public System.Linq.IQueryable<Xrm.ActivityParty> ActivityPartySet
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CreateQuery<Xrm.ActivityParty>();
            }
        }
...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you want exactly, but if it is the have the same method on a set of related services that can be accomplished by adding the method to a base class the services all inherit from or by insuring all the services have the same interface and add an extension method to fill the need. You will have to decide which is best in your case.

Comment: @DavidCulp i thought that perhaps reflection might be the only way to go .... XrmServiceContext is dynamically generated, so i cant force it to follow an interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an extension method + generics is the way to go?

ex

Something along the lines of:

```
public static XrmServiceContextExtensions
{

     public static T GetEntityRecordById<T>(this XrmServiceContext ctx, Guid Id) where T: Entity {
      return ctx.CreateQuery<T>().Where(e => e.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
     }

}
```

But wondering, why not just use the XrmServiceContext directly?

For instance, what I do to keep it simple, is that in my web applications I just keep a reference to the IOrganizationService at the controller level which then I can use to create XrmServiceContext instances from, as well as I could use the same IOrganizationService reference to inject a fake service from a unit test project using FakeXrmEasy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the extension methods in DLaB.Xrm (Nuget package). It provides a generic extension method against the IOrganizationService so it's just

```
service.GetEntity<Account>(id);
```